# what build tools are available for emberjs/handlebars client-side only usage

Tags: node.js, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli, ember-tools

I want to use emberjs to simplify the client-side user interaction and ajax update requests for my rails web site. In [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) they say:

> If you are using build tools to manage your application's assets, most will know how to precompile Handlebars templates and make them available to Ember.js.

and

> If you're using build tools, create a Handlebars file at templates/components/blog-post.handlebars

I know how to precompile handlebar templates through the npm handlebars tool, but that does not seem to work with the components since handlebars doesn't care about folder names.

I searched and found [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools) and [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli), but they all seem to work as a server framework. I do not know much about nodejs as server. So I am not sure whether it is appropriate to choose emberjs in my case, and how should I build handlebar templates (such as components) for emberjs client-side usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ember-CLI, or the Yeoman Ember Generator (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember).

Those tools have a server while you are developing for convenience, but they have a build process that generates all-static files (minified js, compiled templates, etc) that you can publish to any server.

Eg, in Ember-CLI you would run

```
 ember build --environment=production
```

and it would put the generated (static) files in `build/`

Also, take a look at [Use Forever with Ember-CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227756/use-forever-with-ember-cli/25228717#25228717)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I don't have to build templates/components manually, there is a ruby gem that can do that automatically: [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails). It is mentioned in [GETTING EMBER](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-ember/) but I never thought of looking at that page.